# XSLT to join elements bpel

Tags: xslt, append, soa, bpel

I have an input

```
<features>
<feature name="Television" featureSpecID="2000">
    <displayName>TV</displayName>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="Remote" >
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="Cable Box">
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="Carrier"/>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

where I should convert as

```
<productname>Remote;Cable Box;Carrier</productname>
```

I tried my code by doing for-each of parameter

```
<xsl:if test='count(tns:parameters/tns:parameter) > "0"'>
    <xsl:for-each select="tns:parameters/tns:parameter">
       <productname>
         <xsl:value-of select='concat(@name,";")'/>
        </productname>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Out put with my code is:   
        <ns0:Product_Name__c>Remote</ns0:Product_Name__c>
         <ns0:Product_Name__c>Cable Box</ns0:Product_Name__c>
         <ns0:Product_Name__c>Carrier</ns0:Product_Name__c>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<productname>` node should be outside the `<xsl:for-each>` loop. Please modify it as below

```
<productname>
    <xsl:for-each select="tns:parameters/tns:parameter">
        ...
    </xsl:for-each>
</productname>
```

A condition needs to be added to not append the `semi-colon` at the end of the product names according to sample output.

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

XSLT code change

```
<productname>
    <xsl:for-each select="tns:parameters/tns:parameter">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</productname>
```

Output

```
<productname>Remote;Cable Box;Carrier</productname>
```

Comment: in xslt 2, you should use xslvalue-of with separator attribute: <xsl:value-of select="tns:parameters/tns:parameter/@name" separator=";"/>